# how to declare type of a mixed Map?

Tags: typescript, types

```
    private readonly _subscriptions:???? = new Map([
        ['a', new Map()],
        ['b', new Map()],
        ['c', new Map()],
        ['d', []]
        
    ])
```

I can't seem to find a type for this particular map. None worked.

Should be something like Map | []

`private readonly _subscriptions:Map<string, {}|[]> = new Map([`

`private readonly _subscriptions:Map<string, Map<string,[]>|[]> = new Map([`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by

```
private readonly _subscriptions = new Map<string, (Map<any, any> | [])>([
    ['a', new Map()],
    ['b', new Map()],
    ['c', new Map()],
    ['d', []]
]);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for this answer. i try to push a function to 'd'  and it says `Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`.. ok had to use [] as any